# Having Trouble With Closure In Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, closures

I'm trying to pass an array into a function and then use the information in that array to initialize a google map.  However, when I click on a marker on the map, an error is produced which says:

> Unable to get value of the property 'popupHtml': object is null or
>   undefined

The reason for creating the function is so that the javascript code can be moved to a seperate .js file, thus becoming seperate from the html file.  Is there anyway this problem can be corrected?  Here's all my code (I put a comment in to mark where the error is occuring...):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function ()
        {
            function loadMap(markers)
            {
                var options =
                {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.775813, -73.970786),
                    zoom: 17,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

                var points = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
                    points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lon));
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
                {
                    var googleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: points[i], map: map, title: markers[i].title });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(
                        googleMarker,
                        'click',
                        function ()
                        {
                            // The following line is where the error is occuring:
                            infoWindow.setContent(markers[i].popupHtml);
                            infoWindow.open(map, googleMarker);
                        });
                }
            };

            loadMap([{
                "lat": "40.776512",
                "lon": "-73.970293",
                "popupHtml": "\u003cdiv\u003eHello world - from marker 1!\u003c/div\u003e",
                "title": "Marker 1!"
            },
            {
                "lat": "40.774659",
                "lon": "-73.971548",
                "popupHtml": "\u003cdiv\u003eHello world - from marker 2!\u003c/div\u003e",
                "title": "Marker 2!"
            }]);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 680px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the function you're passing into `addListener` has enduring access to the `i` variable, **not** a copy of its value as of when the function was created. So all of the copies of the function see `i` as of when they're called, which is presumably past the end of the array. The same goes for `googleMarker`; they'll all see the *last* value it had in the loop rather than the *current* value.

You fix it by using a generator function or (if you can rely on ECMAScript5, or if you use an ES5 shim since `bind` is something a shim can provide) use [`Function#bind`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5).

Using `bind`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
{
    var googleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: points[i], map: map, title: markers[i].title });
    google.maps.event.addListener(
        googleMarker,
        'click',
        (function (index, thisMarker)
        {
            // The following line is where the error is occuring:
            infoWindow.setContent(markers[index].popupHtml);
            infoWindow.open(map, thisMarker);
        }).bind(undefined, i, googleMarker)
    );
}
```

`bind` returns a function that, when called, will call the original function with a given `this` value and the arguments you give it. So in the above, we call `bind` passing in the *value* of `i` and `googleMarker`, and it gives us a function that, when called, will call our original with those value as arguments. Then we use the arguments (`index` and `thisMarker`) instead of `i` and `googleMarker`.

If you can't rely on ES5 features in your target browsers and you don't want to use a shim, you can use a generator function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
{
    var googleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: points[i], map: map, title: markers[i].title });
    google.maps.event.addListener(
        googleMarker,
        'click',
        makeHandler(i, googleMarker)
    );
}

function makeHandler(index, thisMarker) {
    return function ()
    {
        // The following line is where the error is occuring:
        infoWindow.setContent(markers[index].popupHtml);
        infoWindow.open(map, thisMarker);
    };
}
```

There we're calling `makeHandler`, passing in the *value* of `i` and `googleMarker`, and `makeHandler` returns us a function that closes over those arguments (`index` and `thisMarker`) rather than `i` and `googleMarker`. Since the `makeHandler` arguments won't change, our function will see the correct values.

This all has to do with how closures work. More about closures: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: Thank you T.J.  You were absolutely right about it being a problem with closure.  I've decided to use your solution of a generator function along with one minor modification - I've added an extra parameter to makeHandler so that I can pass in a value for googleMarker.  Apparently, my original script actually had two problems with closure.

Comment: @Andrew: Good deal, glad that helped! And yes, I see what you mean, you had to do it for `googleMarker` too, for the same reason as `i`. I read right past that bit. Just for future readers, I've fixed the answer. Best,

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the loadMap function is in the window.onload handler, and so is not available until the the page has loaded, and even then the function is in a different scope.

I think you've got things a little backwards - I swap the definition of the loadMap function with the call to loadMap so that the calls are within the onload event and the definition isn't.

Comment: The call to `loadMap` is also within the `onload` handler, so there's no problem with scope. The problem is the classic creating-a-function-that-closes-over-a-loop-variable.

Comment: So it is - I answered before I had had my first coffee of the day. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

As T.J Crowder has pointed out, the value of `i` changes as the loop progresses, even within the closure. As well as his answer, a simple approach to fix this is to create a variable within the scope of the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
    {
        var marker = markers[i]; // new variable is created for each loop iteration
        var googleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: points[i], map: map, title: marker.title });
        google.maps.event.addListener(
            googleMarker,
            'click',
            function ()
            {
                // The following line is where the error is occuring:
                infoWindow.setContent(marker.popupHtml);
                infoWindow.open(map, googleMarker);
            });
    }
```

Comment: No, this won't work, for the same reason the OP's code doesn't work. The closure closes over the variable `marker`, and there's only **one** `marker` variable (JavaScript doesn't have block scope [yet], so there is no *"...the scope of the loop..."*). So all of the functions would use the last `marker`, not the `marker` that existed when the function was created.

Comment: Doh! Thanks - I've been telling everyone to do this for ages!

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple anonymous function, so here you execute a function and the context of that execution will hold your step value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
{
    var googleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: points[i], map: map, title: marker.title });

    (function(step){google.maps.event.addListener(
        googleMarker,
        'click',
        function ()
        {
            // The following line is where the error is occuring:
            infoWindow.setContent(markers[step].popupHtml);
            infoWindow.open(map, googleMarker);
        });
    )(i);
}
```